# Convert a jquery to a jquery noConflict

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of javascript code and I must convert it with jquery noConflict in order to make it work with wordpress jquery. Do you have any clue to do this?

```
var initCharts = function() {
var charts = $('.percentage');
  charts.easyPieChart({
    animate: 2000
  });
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `to make it work with wordpress jquery`. What is Wordpress jQuery? Unless Wordpress uses its own version of jQuery then you don't need to prevent conflict

Comment: You would need to call `$.noConflict()` and then wherever you use `$` with jQuery just replace it with `jQuery`.

Comment: Curt wordpress say that about jquery _Note: The jQuery library included with WordPress loads in "no conflict" mode. This is to prevent compatibility problems with other javascript libraries that WordPress can load._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {

var initCharts = function() {
var charts = $('.percentage');
  charts.easyPieChart({
    animate: 2000
  });
}

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It looks like you're passing this function as a `document.ready` handler, which is not quite what the OP's code did.

Comment: @bdesham Wrapping it in a `.ready()` call is going to, at worst, change absolutely nothing, and at best fix an unknown issue with the code executing at the wrong time, since binding `.ready()` when it's already occurred will just immediately execute the passed function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.noConflict();


(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

Based on your code:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var initCharts = function() {
      var charts = $('.percentage');
      charts.easyPieChart({
      animate: 2000
      });
    } 
  });
})(jQuery);
```